# Circular cross-sections characterize spheres

Tags: geometry, contest-math, spheres

> The intersection of a set $A \subset \mathbb{R^3}$ with all planes is always a circle. Prove that $A$ is a sphere.

We regard single points and $\emptyset$ as degenerate circles & spheres.

I was told a partial proof: we can assume that there's at least one non-degenerate intersection, because otherwise $A$ must be $\emptyset$ or a point (a sphere of radius $0$): indeed, if $x_1,x_2 \in A$ then we take a plane passing through both and arrive at a contradiction. Hence there is a circle $A \cap P =C \subset A$. Now we choose a diameter $D$ of $C$ and intersect $A$ with all planes that pass through D's two endpoints This should *somehow* imply that there's a sphere $S \subset A$, and then we note that if $A$ contains a sphere it cannot contain another any other point $x$.

I'd like an explanation of this argument or an alternative proof.

Comment: This question looks similar to one I have answered two years ago. The argument [in my answer there](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/479855/59379) should works for this too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $C_{max}$ the circle of max diameter given by $A \cap P$, with $P$ a plane and $A$ the set.

There is at least one circle of max diameter. Take $D_{max}$ one of the diameter of $C_{max}$.

Take $P_{D_{max}}$ the family of planes that include $D_{max}$.

They all intersect $A$ forming a circle, of diameter already existing $D_{max}$.

By symmetry of rotation, this forms a sphere.