# Proving that a solid is a ball if all plane sections of it are circles

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, recreational-mathematics

> All plane sections of a solid are circles. Prove that the solid is a ball.

Got this from Arthur Engel’s book. The incomplete solution given was as follows;

> Consider the largest chord of the solid. Any section through this cord is a circle whose diameter is the chord. Otherwise the circle and the solid would have a larger chord. Thus the solid is a ball and one of its diameters is the selected chord.

Engels does admit that the proof is not complete, citing that the proof did not address whether a longer chord exists, and that

> In fact, if the surface of the solid did not belong to the solid, a longer chord would not exist. So we assume that the solid is a closed and bounded set. Then we can apply the theorem of *Weierstraβ: A continuous function defined on a closed and bounded set always assumes its global maximum and minimum*.

He finally closes by stating that “*There are also elementary proofs which are slightly longer (see HMO 1954)*”.

My query is whether anyone is able to find elementary proofs to this question, as well as to explain Engel’s solution.

I suspect it can be easily(?) resolved with the use of integration and Riemann sums, but I would much prefer a *purer* proof of the question.

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1331421/42969